# Strongswan on AWS - PING requests not coming back

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, strongswan

I am using Strongswan to connect to a CISCO ASA Firewall through the VPN.

My IPSEC status request looks as following:

```
root@ip-172-31-90-211:~# ipsec status
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
connection-to-vodacom[1]: ESTABLISHED 6 minutes ago, 172.31.90.211[172.31.90.211]...197.235.1.30[197.235.1.30]
connection-to-vodacom{1}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 1, ESP in UDP SPIs: c9fee5f5_i 5a07752a_o
connection-to-vodacom{1}:   172.31.90.211/32 === 10.201.0.0/16
root@ip-172-31-90-211:~#
```

My IPSEC configuration file can be found below:

```
config setup
        charondebug="all"
    uniqueids=no
conn connection-to-vodacom
        type=tunnel
        auto=start
#        keyexchange=ikev1
        authby=secret
#   left=%defaultroute
        left=%any
        leftsubnet=172.31.90.211/32
        right=197.235.1.30
        rightsubnet=10.201.0.0/16
    keyexchange=ikev1
        ike=aes256-sha1-modp1536!
        esp=aes256-sha1!
        aggressive=yes
        keyingtries=%forever
        ikelifetime=86400s
        lifetime=3600s
        dpddelay=30s
        dpdtimeout=120s
        dpdaction=restart
```

The ip xfrm policy command returns the following:

```
oot@ip-172-31-90-211:~# ip xfrm policy
src 172.31.90.211/32 dst 10.201.0.0/16
    dir out priority 375423
    tmpl src 172.31.90.211 dst 197.235.1.30
        proto esp spi 0x5a07752a reqid 1 mode tunnel
src 10.201.0.0/16 dst 172.31.90.211/32
    dir fwd priority 375423
    tmpl src 197.235.1.30 dst 172.31.90.211
        proto esp reqid 1 mode tunnel
src 10.201.0.0/16 dst 172.31.90.211/32
    dir in priority 375423
    tmpl src 197.235.1.30 dst 172.31.90.211
        proto esp reqid 1 mode tunnel
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
    socket in priority 0
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
    socket out priority 0
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
    socket in priority 0
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
    socket out priority 0
src ::/0 dst ::/0
    socket in priority 0
src ::/0 dst ::/0
    socket out priority 0
src ::/0 dst ::/0
    socket in priority 0
src ::/0 dst ::/0
    socket out priority 0
```

Although when i try to ping one of the hosts on the other side of the VPN i get no response, and i can't even see the pings with TSHARK:

```
root@ip-172-31-90-211:~# ping 10.201.47.102
PING 10.201.47.102 (10.201.47.102) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 10.201.47.102 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1017ms
```

And i have the following NAT rules installed:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             policy match dir out pol ipsec
ACCEPT     all  --  ip-10-201-0-0.ec2.internal/16  anywhere             policy match dir out pol ipsec
```

When i try to check the outgoing icmp packets i only manage to see them when the vpn is down when i bring up the vpn i can no longer see the outgoing packets.

Another thing that we manage to notice is that the packets from our server to the VPN leave our server but no packets come back:

```
 125 86.912011656 172.31.90.211 → 197.235.1.30 ESP 174 ESP (SPI=0x6a01228c)
  126 87.039966429 172.31.90.211 → 197.235.1.30 ESP 174 ESP (SPI=0x6a01228c)
  127 87.936001348 172.31.90.211 → 197.235.1.30 ESP 174 ESP (SPI=0x6a01228c)
  128 88.063989799 172.31.90.211 → 197.235.1.30 ESP 174 ESP (SPI=0x6a01228c)
  129 88.960012350 172.31.90.211 → 197.235.1.30 ESP 174 ESP (SPI=0x6a01228c)
  130 89.088001291 172.31.90.211 → 197.235.1.30 ESP 174 ESP (SPI=0x6a01228c)
  131 89.984013008 172.31.90.211 → 197.235.1.30 ESP 174 ESP (SPI=0x6a01228c)
  132 90.111999146 172.31.90.211 → 197.235.1.30 ESP 174 ESP (SPI=0x6a01228c)
  133 90.221484963 197.235.1.30 → 172.31.90.211 UDPENCAP 43 NAT-keepalive
  134 91.008014628 172.31.90.211 → 197.235.1.30 ESP 174 ESP (SPI=0x6a01228c)
  135 91.135994428 172.31.90.211 → 197.235.1.30 ESP 174 ESP (SPI=0x6a01228c)
  136 92.032010593 172.31.90.211 → 197.235.1.30 ESP 174 ESP (SPI=0x6a01228c)
  137 92.159977535 172.31.90.211 → 197.235.1.30 ESP 174 ESP (SPI=0x6a01228c)
  138 93.056014269 172.31.90.211 → 197.235.1.30 ESP 174 ESP (SPI=0x6a01228c)
  139 93.183986406 172.31.90.211 → 197.235.1.30 ESP 174 ESP (SPI=0x6a01228c)
```

Please help

Comment: Why are you using StrongSwan presumably on an EC2 instance rather than using the AWS VPN gateway?  Have you checked your VPC Flow Logs to see what traffic is going where?

Comment: We do see egress packets but we do not see incoming packets @Tim another thing that we noticed is that the egress packets go out with our private IP address, could this be the source issue ?

Comment: Private IPs typically fine over VPNs. Why are you doing this rather than using AWS VPN functions, VPN gateway and such? The managed service is relatively easy, and not particularly expensive.